# Kotlin, unresolved reference on intrinsic data types

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a: int = 12
    var b: double = 1.23

    println("a:$a")
    println("b:$b")
}
```

this results in an 'unresolved reference: int' and 'unresolved reference: float'.
could anyone please tell me why?

Comment: Use capital I and D. In Kotlin all primitive data types are defined via their wrapper class.

Comment: I am speechless. The realization of my own stupidity almost threw me into a sense of nirvana. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're coming from a Java background where `int` and `double` are raw types.  In Kotlin, those types use the capitalized version: `Int` and `Double` respectively.  The reason for this is that the Kotlin compiler will determine at compile time if you need the raw type or the boxed type (an object wrapping the raw type that also allows for nullability).  For your code to work, you'd simply write:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a: Int = 12
    var b: Double = 1.23

    println("a:$a")
    println("b:$b")
}
```

However, as PrafulD pointed out, in this particular scenario, you don't have to specify the types when declaring your variables because Kotlin will infer the types based on the values you've supplied.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need set data type.
Try below code,

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a = 12
    var b = 1.23

    println("a:$a")
    println("b:$b")
}
```

Comment: In this case you are right, but I think declaring a type is always a good way to go, like when you have `val a = getA()`